# Let $E\subset\mathbb{R}$ be a measurable set, and define $F=\{(x,y):x-y\in E\}$. Is $F$ a measurable set?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, measurable-sets

Let $E\subset\mathbb{R}$ be a measurable set, and define $F=\{(x,y):x-y\in E\}$.

Is $F$ a measurable set? why?

Thanks to any one who give me a hint!

Comment: What properties of $m \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to\mathbb{R};\; (x,y) \mapsto x-y$ do you know that could be somehow related to measurability?

Comment: Continuity? But inverse image of a measurable set under continuous map need not be measurable.

Comment: I suppose we're talking about Lebesgue measurability? The continuity gives you that $m^{-1}(B)$ is a Borel set for all Borel sets $B\subset\mathbb{R}$. Thus it reduces the problem to showing that $m^{-1}(N)$ is measurable for all null sets $N$, which is some progress. Now to show the latter, you need to look at more specific properties of $m$, that's true. Hint: without loss of generality, $N$ is bounded, $N\subset [-K,K]$; consider $F_n = \{(x,y) : x-y \in N, \lvert x\rvert \leqslant n, \lvert y\rvert \leqslant n\}$. Estimate the measure of $F_n$. (I'm not saying it's trivial, it isn't.)

Answer (score 1):

By a linear change of coordinates of $\mathbb R^2$ via $(x+y)/2$ and $(x-y)/2$, the map $(x,y)\mapsto x-y$ becomes $(X,Y)\mapsto Y$. (And linear changes of coordinates does not change the measurability of a set.)

Or, equivalently, note that up to scaling by factor of $2$, the map $x-y$ is the projection to the line $y=-x$.

For these maps, that are linear projections, it is clear that inverse image of measurable sets are measurable, because the inverse image of a set $E$ is $E\times \mathbb R$.